# how can I show My Output in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 Tables in MySQL

First is `Sale` and second is `Purchase` I want to see a Stock

[image]

this is My sale table that contains 
Date Quantity ProductName

this is My Purchase Table that Contains sane attributes as sale have 
I perform a Query but i Can not get my desire output

```
SELECT sale.Date, sale.ProductName, SUM(sale.StockQuantityIn) as StockIN, 
        SUM(purchase.StockQuantityout) as Stockout, 
        (SUM(sale.StockQuantityIn)-SUM(purchase.StockQuantityout)) as stock     
from sale 
join purchase on purchase.ProductName=sale.ProductName 
GROUP BY sale.Date,purchase.Date ,purchase.ProductName,sale.ProductName
```

this is the Query and Result is noy my desired output

[image: I want to see like that how can I see on which query for that]

Comment: 1. Format the post. 2. Do not include images. 3. Have in the back of you mind to make answering the question as easy as possible

Comment: stock is not required as it can be calculated from StockIN - Stock out. Before you do any more I advise you to Google Relational database

Answer (score 0):

You cannot join the two tables as you did.

When you join two tables, you can imagine (it is not what really happens, but it helps to understand the result) that all the possible combinations of their rows are evaluated and later filtered based on the "where" constraints.

Try to simulate this process and you will see that the result is what you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very good to `JOIN`, since each line in each table will appear as many times as matched in second table. This is why you get all these extra stockOut.

I would `UNION` 2 queries, one on sale, one on purchase, with ProductName, Date, and StockIn (which would be negative for the query on purchase)

Then I would `GROUP BY` ProductName and Date and `SUM` StockIn